# Audio sample analysis - Comparing two audio samples, the original sample with a reproduction capture sample

Tags: audio, sound-quality, quality, analysis, data

## Introduction

I'm currently working on a project where I'm implementing a basic software phone, which connects two users.
Since I'm implementing both server service and the client applications, I'm able to manipulate the used codec and bitrate used in the audio communication.
At this moment, I'm focused on testing the quality of the audio that is received by a user.

In order to do this, I'm reproducing a testing audio sample (Harvard Sample - Female voice) into a virtual audio device, which is then captured by the sender client and sent to the backend. The backend then resends the audio to the receiver user which will promptly reproduce the audio into a virtual audio device and captured by a recording application (audacity in this case).
At the end of this procedure, I have two audio samples, the original sample and the captured sample.

## My Objective

Now, my objective is to know how degraded is the captured sample in relation to the original sample. For this, **I would like to have a "magic number" from 0 to 100, where 0 would be completely degraded and 100 would be exact match.**

## My Question

**Unfortunately, I do not have a background in audio engineering** and as so, I would like to as the community if my objective is possible to achieve and if so, what kind of audio analysis do I have to do to achieve it.
**If this is not possible or if there are better ways to achieve the quality comparison objective, I am open to other possible suggestions.**
I'm also looking for possible open source libraries that can help me in audio analysis, preferably in Python.

Comment: I started writing a long answer to this but it turns out this is probably not an audio issue but a UX issue: What competition are you up against (zoom, skype, meet, etc) and what quality audio do they provide? If yours is not as good then your users are going to go elsewhere. On top of that, you will have a specific set of users with their own specific audio requirements - you probably need to test with them to understand what they find usable, useful, and comfortable.

Comment: @7HzResearch 

This is not an entrepreneurial project question but a question about audio analysis and signal processing question. The objective is compare an original audio sample with a captured audio sample, to obtain information that can somehow indicate how degraded the captured audio sample is in relation to the original. The cause for that degradation is not important at this moment, as it could be caused by different factors.

Comment: Either way, it's not really a sound design question. It is one of signal processing & would possibly be better suited to https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Tetsujin Okay, thank you for the suggestion. I will transfer the question to there.

Comment: DSP ? Audio ? It is in between. The magic number is a psychoacoustic note. Something which deals more with how our ears function, what are there lack of sensitivity (typically the masking effect). And ears behaviour seems me more an audio subject than a DSP subject.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer I understand your point of view. But I do also think for example, if I had a comparison that would yield a score of 20 were a captured audio sample would be filled with artifacts or some other issue that could prevent the audio from being perceptible, would be very different from an audio sample with a score of 90 which could be seen as something virtually indistinguishable from the original sample.

I'm not looking for a perfect magical value, just something which I can tell me that "this selection of codec and configuration is worse than some other configuration".

Comment: I don’t think MP3, Ogg, and other codec designers start by creating an algorithm which associate to a pair of sample a similitude note. The best way is to create some algorithm based on heuristics (or a single algorithm with a bunch of parameters), and ask some people to assign a note to each transmitted samples or simply ask them which is better. It is not as simple as running an algorithm, but I guess you won’t have such a perfect algorithm.

Comment: See https://listening-test.coresv.net/results.htm#list1, this is a comparison of codec, but it is done with multiple (subjective) notation, not an algorithm.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I also got some answers at [dsp](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/38670/how-can-i-find-snr-peaq-and-odg-values-by-comparing-two-audios)